# Zurb Foundation small-push also applying on large

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am using zurb foundation and adding `small-push-1` but it is also affecting the large panel size.

here is my div structure:

```
<div class="expertise-panel large-5 medium-5 small-push-1 small-10 columns">
</div>
```

anyone ever face the same problem..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're trying to center the small column. Instead of using small-push-1, I think you should use the [centered classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#centered-columns).

This would result in something like this:

```
<div class="expertise-panel small-10 small-centered medium-5 medium-uncentered columns">
</div>
```

Another option is to use the [offset classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#offsets), in that case you should add 'small-offset-1' and 'medium-offset-0' to the class attribute.

Note that you automatically "inherit" styles from smaller classes. It isn't necessary to write 'large-5 medium-5', since medium-5 and large-5 both specify a width of 41.66667%. So if you don't add the large-5 class, the medium width class will be used.

This behaviour also works for the medium-uncentered class. Because I've added medium-uncentered to the expertisepanel, large/xlarge/xxlarge will also automatically become uncentered.